# In primeng Can you use a <p-table> inside a <p-pickList> . I need to display data in table format within the source and target

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying the below . I basically need a p-table in my pick list source and target. The below code does not work . I see no data in the picklist . I see the pic attached. Is this not possible ? 
It would be a bummer if we had to simulate the pick list ourselves inspite of using prime ng heavily in our new product . Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
<p-pickList [source]="sourceCars" [target]="targetCars" showSourceControls="false" showTargetControls="false"> <p-table [responsive]="true"> <ng-template pTemplate="header"> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Type</th> </tr> </ng-template> <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item"> <tr> <td>{{car.label}}</td> <td>{{car.value}}</td> </tr> </ng-template> </p-table> </p-pickList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `p-table` inside `p-pickList`'s `<ng-template pTemplate="item">`

```
<p-pickList [source]="list1" [target]="list2">
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
        <p-table #table [columns]="cols" [value]="sales" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        {{col.header}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
    </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv1h1j) is demo

Comment: Thank you for your response. The move left or move right buttons in the middle do not work. Pick list will treat the whole table as one item and try to move the whole table. Any other suggestions where we can move the individual rows in the table ? TIA.

Comment: This again is not as desired . You can not pick one item from the table and add it to the right. There are multiple headers. I should be able to add only one item "Apple" or "Samsung". The problem in this approach is that there are 2 iterative loops. Once for ng-template and another for the table.

Comment: So use normal HTML (inside pickList template) instead of table